# microsoft edge shows error cert invalid on accessing private applications

Tags: macos, https, ssl-certificate, microsoft-edge

Downloaded Edge version 84.0.522.59 on mac, while opening private sites getting error cert invalid and no option to **proceed anyway** while clicking advanced tab.

This is to inform others, if someone face a similar kind of issue.

Resolved using:

1. get your applications certificate locally.
2. (on mac) Go to applications> keychain Access> System> Import your certificate.
3. Click on imported certificate, You will see Trust and Details heads for your imported certificate.
4. Elaborate Trust head and change permission to Always Trust.
5. Save your changes.
6. Refresh your application on edge browser.

It should make your private/local secured application accessible on edge.

Comment: Hi @user3537338, it would be better if you separated your post into a question and an answer, just cut the answer form the question and paste it as your own answer to your question, that way the community can vote it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Sure, will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using:

```
get your applications certificate locally.
(on mac) Go to applications> keychain Access> System> Import your certificate.
Click on imported certificate, You will see Trust and Details heads for your imported certificate.
Elaborate Trust head and change permission to Always Trust.
Save your changes.
Refresh your application on edge browser.
```

It should make your private/local secured application accessible on edge.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the cert of my page by downloading an old version of chromium  (70) https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/708905/ and dragging and dropping the cert into finder, then following existing advice